# Set class that extends TCPDF

Tags: php, symfony, oop

In Symfony I'm using TCPDF package for creating PDF documents and I have it installed via composer. I need to modify `TCPDF` class a little before I use it in production, so I created `MyPDF` class that extends `TCPDF` class and that is stored in the same file as original class (`Symfony-project/vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php`).

Problem is, that every time I update composer and new version of TCPDF package is installed, file `tcpdf.php` is being replaced, so class `MyPDF` disappears. What is consider as best practice for creating and storing such classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not work in the `vendor/` directory. It is preserved for external code only. Here is what you can do:

- You could **fork the TCPDF repository** and apply their changes. Afterwards you just use your own fork of that repo. Downside of this is that you might miss out on important bug-fixes. If the patch you apply to the code is important for anyone you are also welcome to **open a pull-request** to merge your fix back into the main repository.
- You could create a **service that extends the TCPDF classes**. Here is my service definition using [this repository](https://github.com/r1pp3rj4ck/tcpdf):

  ```
  <service id="pdfgenerator" class="TCPDF">
      <file>%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/r1pp3rj4ck/tcpdf/tcpdf.php</file>
      <argument key="orientation">P</argument>
      <argument key="unit">mm</argument>
      <argument key="format">A4</argument>
  </service>
  ```

  Your can extend this service as you like.

### Edit:

See the [Github HowTo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) on how to fork a repository. After you have your own fork you can edit the code to your needs. After you are done and your repository is ready you just include your own repository instead of the current *TCPDF* repository. See the [composer docs for more information](http://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#loading-a-package-from-a-vcs-repository). 
You should add something like this to your `composer.json`:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/..."
        }
     ],
     "require": {
         ".../tcpdf": "dev-master"
     }
 }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using WhiteOctober package for TCPDF integration into Symfony. So the class file is set to %kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/tecnick.com/tcpdf/tcpdf.php and I only changed default class in configuration to MyPDF.

Comment: Still checkout my other advice. Working in the `vendor/` dir is very bad practice. Fork the repository instead!

Comment: I don't understand how to do it. And will there be still ability to get updates through composer?

Comment: But that doesn't solve my question, because it would break the package updating.

Comment: You asked for *best practice* on how to edit external vendor code. This is how you are intended to do so. Or extend a new service as I described in my answer aswell.

Comment: Thanks for help, but I can't simply use service that extends the TCPDF classes since I'm using whiteoctober/tcpdf-bundle. So I have to select file and class to work with, not the service.